# Android:retrieve data stored in sharedpreference even after closing the application

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have checkboxes in my application and used shared preference method to save them, I finally stored the data in shared preference and able to retrieve it but only when the app is not fully closed.

here is my code for saving my data

```
save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

             prefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("preferencename", MODE_PRIVATE); 
            editor = prefs.edit(); 
            editor.clear();
            editor.commit();

            saveArray(list, "list", getApplicationContext());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Save"+" "+cou, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            cou=0;

        }
    });

}
```

method for saving it

```
 public boolean saveArray(List<Model> list2, String arrayName, Context mContext) {   



prefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("preferencename", MODE_PRIVATE); 
editor = prefs.edit();  
        for(int i=0;i<list2.size();i++){
            if(list2.get(i).isSelected()){

            editor.putString(arrayName +"."+i, "true"); 
            cou++;
            }else{ editor.putString(arrayName +"."+i, "false");}

        }
        return editor.commit();  
    }
```

data retrieving

```
    try
     {
          adapter = new CustomAdapter(this,loadArray("list", getApplicationContext()));

     }
    catch(Exception e){

         adapter = new CustomAdapter(this,getModel()); 
    }
```

method for retrieving

```
public List<Model> loadArray(String arrayName, Context mContext) {  
    prefs= getSharedPreferences("preferencename", MODE_PRIVATE); 
         String mp3Directory = "/Music";
         String directoryPath= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+mp3Directory;
      lst = getMP3Files(directoryPath); 

    //print in LogCat the list of .mp3:

        for(int i=0;i<lst.size();i++){
            list.add(new Model(lst.get(i).getName()));

             if(prefs.getString(arrayName+"." +i, "")=="true")
             {
                    list.get(i).setSelected(true);
             }
                else
                    list.get(i).setSelected(false);
            }

        return list;

    }  
}
```

Comment: use services..call it from there when your up is closed

Comment: where am i gonna put this services, and can you please give me some idea about it, like a sample program @Elltz

Comment: was it helpful? did it solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

create a class which extends service, and i do not know your preference but here are some tuts to get yourself around services [one](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) , [two](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) , [three](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html) , [four](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_services.htm)

```
public class MyBackgroundjob extends Service {
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // call it here..
    loadArray(String arrayName, Context mContext); // 
    // you can create a singleton class that will hold your data, which will be global
    // to your application, and yea, now you have your stuff do your stuff

    return START_STICKY;
  }
  // copy your retrieving method and paste the void here.. starting from this line

List<Model> loadArray(String arrayName, Context mContext) {  
prefs= getSharedPreferences("preferencename", MODE_PRIVATE); 
     String mp3Directory = "/Music";
     String directoryPath= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+mp3Directory;
  lst = getMP3Files(directoryPath); 

//print in LogCat the list of .mp3:

    for(int i=0;i<lst.size();i++){
        list.add(new Model(lst.get(i).getName()));

         if(prefs.getString(arrayName+"." +i, "")=="true")
         {
                list.get(i).setSelected(true);
         }
            else
                list.get(i).setSelected(false);
        }

    return list;

   }  
 }
}
```

btw, you start the service (MyBackgroundJob class) from your activity like this `Intent i = new Intent(activity, MyBackgroundJob.class); context.startService(i);`

your signleton class could be

```
public class Mysingle extends Application{
   // then you create your "list" here okay make it static
   static List<type> list; // and you call it by =  Mysingle.list

}
```

yea so play with the rest.. you can even run your whole app process in the service and bind to your activity and update the user, make use of the tuts. ayt..

hope i am sensible and lucid..